# How to drag&drop row from one CellTable to another using GWTquery?

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

I'm following the example about DragAndDropCellTable in GWTQuery example where the drop target is a CellList. What i need to do is Drag a CellTable row and Drop it in another CellTable. Is it possible? Any Pointers? I'm using GWT2.4

Comment: [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gwtquery/GYPFyvE4ttU/discussion) you can find how to rearrange rows into the same table. From there, should be easy with two tables.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i need to do it between multiple cell tables! and i'm searching for a pattern to implement it